# How do I link my main window to a dialog so that when I select File -> New, my "new thing" dialog opens?

Tags: python, dialog, qt5, program-entry-point, designer

I am writing my first application using Qt5 and I am using Qt Designer to lay out the windows. I have created a main window, which includes a menu bar and saved it as main.ui. I have also created a simple QDialog window and saved it as new.ui. I want to be able to select "File -> New..." from the menus and it will open the QDialog window.

I am trying to understand the typical workflow here. Is this connectivity something I create within Qt Designer? When I try to assign an action using the Signals and Slots edit mode for the main window, I cannot select the QDialog window as the receiver. I assume this is because the QDialog is in a separate file. I also cannot see a way to build the QDialog within main.ui.

I suspect that the answer is that I have to make that connection in code outside of Qt Designer, which would be okay. But I could also see it being a "cleaner" workflow if the connection could be made within Qt Designer.

Comment: There are tasks that can be done with QtDesigner and others cannot. So you already have the answer: *I have to make that connection in code outside of Qt Designer*

Comment: Thanks, @ellanesc! That's what I suspected, but I have completely misunderstood other tools before.